# Having trouble with getting Enterprise traps to be encrypted with net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am at a loss on this one.

I am using net-snmp version 5.7.3 and recently added support in the application to support SNMP v3.

SNMP GETS are working flawlessly with any combination of Auth and Priv protocol. I can see the encrypted PDU's when I capture with Wireshark and the MIB browser is able to decode and all works fine.

The problem I am having is with SNMP v3 traps. For the life of me I cannot get Enterprise traps to be encrypted. Wireshark capture shows them clearly going out in clear text.

Here is my relevant configuration:

In /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf I have:

```
master agentx
agentaddress udp:161
engineID 43f8513afdd8a1648e63a728be8625
rouser allenmcw priv
trapsess -v 3 -u allenmcw -a SHA -A <authPass>-x AES -X <privPass> <IP address>
```

In /usr/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf I have:

```
 usmUser 1 3 "43f8513afdd8a1648e63a728be8625" "allenmcw" "allenmcw" NULL .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.1.3 0x11c712fff7718594a12d2444a3356405a31b3c9c .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.2.4 0x11c712fff7718594a12d2444a3356405 0x
setserialno 746862596
##############################################################
#
# snmpNotifyFilterTable persistent data
#
##############################################################


    engineBoots 42
    oldEngineID "43f8513afdd8a1648e63a728be8625"
```

For trapsess I have tried the following variation as my understanding is that the passphrase, etc should be picked up with the usmUser entry.

trapsess -v 3 -u allenmcw -l authPriv

Note that this last option results in NO trap going out at all! The -l option should be valid based on all research I have done but it is not working for me.

It should be NOTED that the COLD start trap sent out by net-snmp itself IS getting encrypted, but NO enterprise level traps are.

I confess to being somewhat lost at this point as to what the problem could be.

Thanks for any guidance.

Allen

Comment: The following made it work:

trapsess -v 3 -u allenmcw -e 43f8513afdd8a1648e63a728be8625 -l authPriv -a SHA -A testing1 -x AES -X testing1 <IP address>

It won't work without actually putting the passwords in which I don't like since they are clear text.

It should be noted a separate process daemon runs which takes care of sending the enterprise traps but it would seem that it should still get the passwords from the usmUser entry in the other file.

Answer (score 0):

Have the solution. I suspect this occurred because in our environment we run a separate trap daemon to send all the enterprise traps.

Rather than have clear text passwords in the /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf the following will allow the trap daemon to use the HASHED version of the passwords which comes from /usr/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf

Here is the corrected trapsess line:

```
trapsess -v 3 -u allenmcw -3m 0x9d833d009db321cec1d2f1ed737bf11aff770fa1 -3M 0x9d833d009db321cec1d2f1ed737bf11a <IP address>
```

These hashed values were pulled from the other snmpd.conf referenced.

Comment: The solution appears to not work consistently 100% of the time. I'll update again after further debugging.

Comment: Do you also use "snmptrapd" as the traps daemon? Did you get the hashed passwords from "snmptrapd.conf" after daemon restart?